# Is there any PostGIS st_makevalid equivalent for use in Esri's sde.st_geometry?

Tags: postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, st-geometry

I am inserting into an Enterprise Geodatabase (Postgres running sde.st_geometry).

I am encountering errors on inserts when a multipolygon has parts with a zero-area.

I know of Desktop's Repair Geometry tool, but I would like to make this fix via backend query.

Does Esri sde.st_geometry have anything that can detect this faulty polygons and remove/fix them?